# math book typo in "Work out the size of the angle the second hand of the clock turns through in 55 seconds."

Tags: grammaticality

I have a math book in which there this question :

***"Work out the size of the angle the second hand of the clock turns through in 55 seconds."***

Is that sentence correct? Why there is not a ***"of"*** between **"angle"** and the **"the second hand"**

Then see my proposition :

***"Work out the size of the angle travelled by the second hand of the clock after 55 seconds."***

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: @YosefBaskin In fact 'of' would be completely out of place in that sentence. "The size of the angle" is one concept and, as you say, "_that_ the second hand turns through" is another one. You can't join those concepts by putting "of" in there.

Comment: The whole expression is bloated and confusing. Asking for the “size of the angle” is like asking for the “size of the length”. If the intent is to test the student’s understanding of clocks and circles, it would be easier and simpler to ask: What is the angle swept out by the second hand of a (stationary) clock in 55 seconds?

Comment: Yours is a “zero-*that*” construction. It is correct, if not easy to follow. *Work out the size of the angle [**that**] the second hand of the clock turns through in 55 seconds.*

Comment: an angle is a geomtric figure, therefore a mathematic object, that's why we say the measure of an angle or its size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand the phrase "the second hand of the clock turns through in 55 seconds." as a relative clause. The relative pronoun "that" can be omitted when it functions as the object of this clause.

> Work out the size of the angle [that] the second hand of the clock turns through in 55 seconds.

The relative clause is related to a main clause like

> The second hand of the clock turns through [this angle] in 55 seconds.

So you see the pronoun "that" functions as the object of the verb phrase "turns through".  In this case the word "that" can be omitted.

> It is an apple the man had bitten. = It is an apple *that* the man had bitten because "the man had bitten *this apple*".  The word "that" is optional.